# Silverlight set stackpanel position center of screen

Tags: silverlight

I'm using StackPanels in Silverlight 5 (VS2012), how can I center them in screen? is there any property (horizontalalignemt & verticalalignment do nothing), or should I center them using code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put stack panel in a container like Grid control then horizontal and vertical alignment properties should work.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right"> </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: it doesn't work, my stackpanel is displayed on top-right corner of screen, should I set any property for grid? its width or eight for example?

Comment: it worked! I set width & height of grid as my screen size, then it worked! thanks